# issues in displaying fetched data in a dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am fetching a list of users from server inside useEffect hook and trying to display it inside a HTML select dropdown. something like this, [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-tereshkova-pbfh6?file=/src/App.js) 
As you can see there is nothing showing up in the dropdown. But at the same time all the data is present as it is being displayed in the list below.

I tried by implementing normal HTML select without any library, currently am using react-select. Also I tried this:

```
{ posts? (<Select options={posts}) : null }
```

But no success. What am I missing here?? How can I display the fetched data from server in the dropdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `getOptionLabel` prop on `Select`.

**[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hermann-vsc7q)**

`<Select options={posts} getOptionLabel={item=>item}/>`

**[From the Docs](https://react-select.com/props)**

`getOptionLabel typeof getOptionLabel = (option) => string`

Resolves option data to a string to be displayed as the label by components

Comment: And why was it not working without any library? I mean, first I tried by simply writing normal HTML select without using any nom library.

Answer (score 1):

**react-select** accepts value and label attribute. Either update your field or use same key as **react-select** accepts.

```
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;
    axios.get(url, config).then(res => {
      setPosts(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  let updatedData = posts.map(post=> ({...post, label:post.title, value:post.title}))
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello React CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="side-by-side">
        <h3>Latest Posts</h3>
        <div className="side-by-side">
          <span style={{ paddingRight: "20px" }}>Show Posts</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Select options={updatedData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working [Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-feather-1zhb8?file=/src/App.js:139-891)